# File opens on single click

Tags: windows-7, mouse-click

In windows 7 when I single click a file or folder it opens it. yet when I go to:

explorer.exe > Windows Explorer  > Menubar > tools > folder options > general

the radio button: 'double click to open an item, single click to select' is selected and everything else is grayed out.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The other options are greyed out unless you select 'open file with single click' option.

Comment: @Biswa no, that is also greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

As i can't comment; need more rep - Have you tried another mouse as it's entirely possible your double is double click when you single click due to the button being faulty/broken

Comment: I just tried  but it still does the same.

Comment: What about the tried and tested solution for most IT problems; restart the computer - failing that re-download the driver (or uninstall and re-install from device manager)